# Can I set distinct connection vs. query timeout values for MySQL on Linux?

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, database-connection

I'd like for MySQL queries to have a long-ish timeout, but the initial connection timeout to be short. E.g. If a process can't connect for 3 seconds, assume the server may be overloaded and fail right away (rather than queuing up httpd connections), but if the MySQL connection occurs quickly, give queries plenty of time to complete.

While I assume I can specify a server-wide connection timeout via MySQL's config, it looks impossible to configure within PHP because, as the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.connect-timeout) says, "On Linux [the `mysql.connect_timeout`] setting is also used for waiting for the first answer from the server."

Does "the first answer" mean the result of the first query? Does `SET NAMES 'utf8'` count?

Does this imply `mysql.connect_timeout` applies to *all* queries on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

see the PHP document page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php

the example #1

EDIT 1

as soon you connect to a mysql the client receive a "banner" where the server declare his version and other stuff.

"On Linux [the mysql.connect_timeout] setting is also used for waiting for the first answer from the server." means that the client wait for this "banner communication" using the same timeout of the connect.

in my test i set a timeout of 4 seconds (see the 4000 in the poll):

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3306), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
fcntl64(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)             = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, **4000**) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\2003\341\1\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "\2003\341\1\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4)   = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, **4000**)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
read(3, "4\0\0\0\n5.1.55"..., 16384) = 56
```

My server is 5.1.55 version!

In brief: **connection_timeout is non related to any timeout on queries**

Comment: Note that this is the mysql**i** driver.